# textShouldEndEditing does not work with stepper

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, delegates

I am working with swift 4 for macOS and I have this view controller content:

I have a textfield and stepper. I can change the value of the textfield manually or with the stepper.

I would like to get a print result, if the value of this textfield did change. For this I tried this delegate methode:

```
func control(_ control: NSControl, textShouldEndEditing fieldEditor: NSText) -> Bool {

   print("VALUE CHANGED")    
   return true

}
```

If I change it manually => I get "VALUE CHANGED"

If I change it with the stepper => I get no "VALUE CHANGED"

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Are problem 1 and problem 2 related?

Comment: i updated my first post. the problems with the textview was solved. but the problem with the stepper is actual there

Comment: The stepper doesn't edit the textfield. If you change the value of the textfield in code you're already aware of the change.

Comment: okay, can you write this as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stepper doesn't edit the textfield. If you change the value of the textfield in code you're already aware of the change.